# Wait x seconds before closing a program c++

Tags: c++, winapi

Just to be clean: im new in c++.

Hi, i have a question how do i close a program after x seconds?

thats what i tried so far but, the process dont wait the sleep and auto exit him self:

```
    if (LoadProcess("test.exe"))
{
    printf("Please close test.exe.");
    Sleep(20);
    exit(1);
}
```

Load Process code:

```
bool manualmap::LoadProcess(const char* procName)
{
    HANDLE hProcessId = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof(pEntry);

    do
    {
        if (!strcmp(pEntry.szExeFile, procName))
        {
            dwProcessId = pEntry.th32ProcessID;
            CloseHandle(hProcessId);

            hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, dwProcessId);
            return (processOk = true);
        }

    } while (Process32Next(hProcessId, &pEntry));

    return (processOk = false);
}
```

Comment: `Sleep(x*1000)` since `Sleep()` takes argument in milliseconds.

Comment: If you've tried that code, what did you experience?

Comment: It is **operating system specific**. Your code won't work on Linux. Your question lacks some additional tag, and some [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also care what OS you are using. `Sleep` for Windows takes the argument in milliseconds, `sleep` in a Linux environment uses seconds.

Comment: On Windows you can use the [`Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx) function

Comment: Not directly related, but the `LoadProcess` function is fishy. Where is the declaration of  `processOk`?

Comment: ... and you don't close the `hProcess` handle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function `sleep` is not in the standard C++ so you have to check what it does in the [winapi reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you're using the standard c++ the function you need is [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

> Note that you can pass both 20s and 20000ms, the suffix tells the compiler which unit you meant. (Suffixes from using namespace std::chrono_literals) – MSalters

Comment: This question is tagged "winapi" so the use of `Sleep()` seems completely appropriate to actually perform a sleep, even though there are other ways to do it.

Comment: Note that you can pass both `20s` and `20000ms`, the suffix tells the compiler which unit you meant. (Suffixes from `using namespace std::chrono_literals`)

Comment: @GregHewgill At the time I answered the question it was only tagged with C++

Comment: Irrespective of the tagging, the call to `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` makes this a pure win32 question

Answer (score 0):

Add a newline after your output:

```
printf("Please close test.exe.\n");
                              ^^
```

Comment: This changes the output. Perhaps using `fflush` would be better

Comment: Wait ... is this a comment? Or does the newline really change how the code waits (or not)?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi: It doesn't change the wait itself, but it _does_ print the statement immediately. It's quite likely that the buffered `printf` simply kept the partial line in an internal buffer, until the `exit` statement.